# How to start using Windows box after vagrant up successfully?

Tags: windows, virtualbox, vagrant

I am new to Vagrant with Windows using VirtualBox and I follow the example mentioned [here](http://kwilson.me.uk/blog/provisioning-a-windows-server-vagrant-box-with-iis-net-4-5-and-octopus-deploy/).

All is good and I am able to vagrant up dev to the dev machine.

I see this message:

```
==> dev: Booting VM...
==> dev: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    dev: WinRM address: 127.0.0.1:5985
    dev: WinRM username: vagrant
    dev: WinRM execution_time_limit: PT2H
    dev: WinRM transport: plaintext
==> dev: Machine booted and ready!
==> dev: Checking for guest additions in VM...
==> dev: Setting hostname...
==> dev: Configuring and enabling network interfaces...
==> dev: Mounting shared folders...
    dev: /vagrant => C:/vagrant_getting_started

C:\vagrant_getting_started>
```

So how am I going to start using my machine? For I can't see any new windows being loaded with the machine?

I can't use vagrant ssh as this is not a Linux but a Windows box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of googling, I just realized I need this command:

```
vagrant rdp
```

The above requires some settings to be enabled in the box ferventcoder/win2008r2-x64-nocm, which includes:

- WinRM
- Remote Desktop

I am posting [that article](http://huestones.co.uk/node/305) here for everyone benefits in the future.